# How to solve truncated SVD problem with the constraint that the left and right singular vector spaces are the same?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, svd, nuclear-norm

Given $M \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$, I would like to find its $k$-dimensional "leading singular vector space". $M$ is not necessarily symmetric. In contrast with the standard SVD problem, the left and right $k$-dimensional "leading singular vector spaces" must  be the same.

Formally, the optimization problem in $U \in \mathbb R^{n \times k}$ and $Q \in \mathbb R^{k \times k}$ is as follows

$$\hat{U} = \arg\max_{U^T U = I_k} \,\max_{Q^T Q = I_k} \mbox{tr} \left( U^T M U Q \right)$$

An equivalent problem is to solve

$$\arg \max_{U^T U = I_k} \|U^T M U\|_*$$

Here $\|\cdot\|_*$ denotes the nuclear norm, i.e., the sum of singular values.

---

**Remark**: I understand that the slightly different problem

$$\arg\max_{U^T U = I,V^T V = I} \|U^T M V\|_*$$

will be solved by finding the spaces spanned by the leading $k$ left and right singular vectors of $M$. However, I could not figure out how to solve the new problem.

Comment: Please let me know if you agree with my edits.

Comment: Thank you. That's much clearer!

Comment: This appears to be difficult even when $M$ is symmetric and positive definite.

Comment: If $M$ is symmetric and positive definite, wouldn't the problem be solved by the leading singular vectors of $M$? Because the SVD and the eigenvalue decomposition of $M$ will be the same is this case, which solves the problem in the remark and already has $U$ and $V$ identical.